# Spatial Averaging a Pixel's colors

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

How can I spatially average the colors of every single pixel in a photo? Im trying to spatially average the pixels themselves. By the way, I am working in python.

I haven't really implemented code for this issue, as I am still researching the process for coding this. I was originally planning on spatially averaging the photo as a whole.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean my spatial averaging. Do you want to perform a pooling operation?

Comment: Sorry, I want to perform a linear spatial filter. Is that any better? If not, I can provide code on what I mean by "spatially averaging" a photo.

Comment: Sounds like a simple box blur to me. If so, use a 3x3 convolution with 1,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,1 as coefficients and divide result by 9.

Comment: Add your input and  expected output images and your code if you want a proper answer.

Comment: Oh, my reply didn't get posted. Thank you for your initial comment Mark, I am using it.